# Little boy who is lonely, meets future mom

Tags: story-identification

Looking for the name of the show/episode/story about a young boy who is living with his parents who are not really seen.  He is becoming lonely and one day he meets a pregnant woman who tries to comfort him and tells him his parents love him but they are busy.

I remember  one scene when the refrigerator disappears and cookies come flying out of a pantry.  Subsequently, a man comes to his home and tells him it's time to be born . . . of course the woman turns out to be his mom.

Comment: Can you provide any additional clues like when you saw the story?

Comment: I also saw that. It was in a Twilight Zone style show. It may well have been "The Outer Limits"
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Delivering Milo was a nice movie, but not what I have been looking for. It probably took was run in the 90's. Yes to all, it was an anthology show. Still looking, but have not found it. It has become anitch in my brain!! 

Answer (score 5):

This plot sounds so familiar....I think I must've read it in passing somewhere, I feel like for an episode of an anthology show like *Outer Limits* or something.

Anyways, this film, [*Delivering Milo* (2001)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delivering_Milo), seems to match:

> Elizabeth believes she has gone into labor, but at the hospital, the
> doctor tells her she was having Braxton Hicks contractions. The
> reality is that in the world from which babies come, Milo is too
> scared to leave the comfortable place where he has lived. Since babies
> must be born in order, no other babies will be born until Milo changes
> his mind. The people in charge give the job of educating Milo to
> Elmore, who is in a kind of limbo until he proves he is worthy of
> Heaven.
>
> Elmore and Milo go out the door which normally serves only as an
> entrance. Outside is the energetic and terrifying New York City.
> Elmore loves it, but Milo doesn't want to be in this scary place.
>
> The big news story is the lack of births anywhere.
>
> Elmore eventually takes Milo to Atlantic City, where he loved to
> gamble when he was alive. Elizabeth also ends up in Atlantic City.
> Milo's mind is not changed and there is a deadline. A door will close
> and no more babies will ever be born. In Atlantic City, Elizabeth
> meets Milo, who realizes Elizabeth is his mother, and decides he wants
> to be born. He also realizes Elmore is the father who abandoned
> Elizabeth.

Does that sound like the work you saw?

Answer (score 0):

Think it's "what if" an amazing story

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511130/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl

http://www.tv.com/shows/amazing-stories/what-if--69867/cast/