# What movie featured children being born after going through a door?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I slightly remember the plot, but that too is blurry. I have watched the film long ago, and I only remember that there was a woman who was supposed to have a baby, and there was a group of children waiting for some kind of door, basically when they went through the door, they would get born.

Comment: Roughly how long ago was "long ago"? Was it in color? English? Can you describe any of the characters?

Comment: It is possibly [this story](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71419/2865)?

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but there is a play, "Deliver Us Not (or Oh Birth, Where Is Thy Sting?) with that as its theme (with many jokes about religion and the afterlife) in the process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24LxzFteU0s

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but similar... Saturday's Warrior https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--w9bOGpi2s

Answer (score 5):

There is a similar scene in [The Blue Bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blue_Bird_(1940_film)), a 1940 movie starring Shirley Temple - one of the places the children visit is a land of children yet to be born.

At the end of the scene, a group of children can be seen heading through a door off on a journey to be born.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [*Delivering Milo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212910/)? It's a 2001 film starring Anton Yelchin as the eponymous Milo.

[Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delivering_Milo):

> Elizabeth believes she has gone into labor, but at the hospital, the doctor tells her she was having Braxton Hicks contractions. The reality is that in the world from which babies come, Milo is too scared to leave the comfortable place where he has lived. Since babies must be born in order, no other babies will be born until Milo changes his mind. The people in charge give the job of educating Milo to Elmore, who is in a kind of limbo until he proves he is worthy of Heaven.
>
> Elmore and Milo go out the door which normally serves only as an entrance. Outside is the energetic and terrifying New York City. Elmore loves it, but Milo doesn't want to be in this scary place.
>
> The big news story is the lack of births anywhere.
>
> Elmore eventually takes Milo to Atlantic City, where he loved to gamble when he was alive. Elizabeth also ends up in Atlantic City. Milo's mind is not changed and there is a deadline. A door will close and no more babies will ever be born. In Atlantic City, Elizabeth meets Milo, who realizes Elizabeth is his mother, and decides he wants to be born. He also realizes Elmore is the father who abandoned Elizabeth.